# Listing distinct values in Amazon Cloudwatch Log Insights Query Language

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch

Im digging through some logs and need to find what distinct users make up the distinct values in the query.
Is there a way to list these values in this language.

The query:

```
fields @timestamp, @message, @app
| filter @logStream like /api/
| filter user like /nyc/ 
| filter event="page-view"
| parse url 'THE_URL'
| stats count_distinct(user)
```